# Php output to xml error

Tags: php, xml

I am following step by step this tutorial http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html . I have tried all the 3 ways to output data to an xml file . But i get error  **"error on line 9 at column 1: internal error"** which is the line that php script begins. Connection to database is ok. tables and fields are ok. 
I tried and copy pasted the exact code from google's tutorial (same values everywhere) to check if there was a problem with my database engine or something and I got an error again this time **error on line 10 at column 8: Extra content at the end of the document** that is `$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr);`

I am running  XAMPP 1.7.4 [PHP: 5.3.5]

Comment: That's not a PHP error message... what's generating that message? As well, don't use str_replace to do entity encoding. Use `htmlspecialchars()` - that's what it's there for.

Comment: Well i dont know exactly what generates this message. And the weird thing is that when i try with googlesroginal code same filenames and same values even in the database i still get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the php script not to include the file containing the username and password for the database. I manually included those to the script. Not sure why it wasnt working as provided from google instructions but anyway now i get the job done.